# How to use a lein exec task in :release-tasks when releasing a clojure leiningen project?

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I am using [lein exec](https://github.com/kumarshantanu/lein-exec) plugin tasks as tasks in my :release-tasks vector but every time one of those lein exec tasks finishes the rest of the release tasks don't run.

My :release-tasks are:

```
$ lein pprint :release-tasks
[["vcs" "assert-committed"]
 ["change" "version" "leiningen.release/bump-version" "release"]
 ["exec" "bin/set-version-from-project.clj"]
 ["vcs" "commit"]
 ["vcs" "tag"]
 ["exec" "bin/make-bin.clj"]
 ["change" "version" "leiningen.release/bump-version"]
 ["exec" "bin/set-version-from-project.clj"]
 ["vcs" "commit"]
 ["vcs" "push"]]
```

And when I release it stops at the first exec task like so but returns a successful exit code:

```
$ DEBUG=1 lein release
Leiningen's classpath: /Users/paul/.lein/self-installs/leiningen-2.5.0-standalone.jar
Applying task release to []
Applying task change to [version leiningen.release/bump-version release]
Applying task exec to [bin/set-version-from-project.clj]
$ echo $?
0
```

And when I run the exec task by itself it runs correctly and returns a successful exit code:

```
$ lein exec bin/set-version-from-project.clj
$ echo $? 
0
```

How can I get all of these :release-tasks to run in order?

Answer (score 2):

I switched from the lein-exec plugin to the [lein-oneoff](https://github.com/mtyaka/lein-oneoff) plugin.  It's a similar plugin and works with :release-tasks.

Here's the working :release-tasks.

```
$ lein pprint :release-tasks
[["vcs" "assert-committed"]
 ["change" "version" "leiningen.release/bump-version" "release"]
 ["oneoff" "bin/set-version-from-project.clj"]
 ["vcs" "commit"]
 ["vcs" "tag"]
 ["oneoff" "bin/make-bin.clj"]
 ["change" "version" "leiningen.release/bump-version"]
 ["oneoff" "bin/set-version-from-project.clj"]
 ["vcs" "commit"]
 ["vcs" "push"]]
```